# python web scrape - any easy way to parse the script tag

Tags: python

I am trying to get some information out of the following script tag during web scraping, like jobTitle, size, industry. Is there any easy and reproducible way of doing this? since I need to scrape a lot of pages.

I tried converting it to a string, strip off the front and tail extra part, then use `eval` but it shows a syntax error.

```html
<script>
 window.gdGlobals = window.gdGlobals ||
  [{
   'analyticsId':                      "UA-2595786-1",

   
   'analyticsUrl':                     "/jobview/jobs/joblisting/Teradata Corporation",

   'deferredScriptType':               "text/x-deferred-js",
   'accessDeniedRedirectUrl':          '',
   'locale':        'en-US',
   'env': 'prod',


   'device':       {

        
        'handheld':     false,

        
        'tablet':        false,
        'deviceTypeId':  1,
        'platformTypeId':  3,
        'viewTypeId':   4
       },
   'page':         {
        
        'domain':       "www.glassdoor.com",
        'domainId':  1,

        
        'domainSuffix': "",

        
        'group':        "JobListing",

        
        'guid':         '000001675b5fa6a78fa0ac61fe36e9b6',

        
        'flex':         true,

        
        'section':      "job-listing",

        
        'type':         "job-listing:job-listing",

        
        'id':           "job-listing:job-listing",

        'med': '',

        'src' : '',
        'content' : '',
        'campaign' : '',
        'term' : '',
        'state' : 'locked',
        'untranslatedUrl' : 'https://www.glassdoor.com/job-listing/service-management-business-analyst-teradata-JV_IC1147311_KO0,35_KE36,44.htm?jl=3032410565'
                                
       },
   'user':         {
        
        'guid':         '2917b9da-9897-4a3b-90c6-da49238a5924',

        
        'ipAddr':       "70.95.16.113",

        
        'locale':       "en_US",

        
        'country':      "US",
        'ipLocationId': "1147311",
        'ipLocationType': "C",
        
        'elligibleForAppBoy': false
       },
   'vendor':       {
        'fbReqPerms':   ""
       },
   
   'search':       {
    "rawKeyword":""
    
   },
   'employer' : {
    
      'size' : "10000--1",
     
      'sector' : "Information Technology",
      'sectorId' : "10013",
     
      'industry' : "Computer Hardware &amp; Software",
      'industryId' : "200060",
     
     'name':"Teradata",
     'id' : "14638"
                    
        ,'location': "San Diego"
        ,'locationId': "1147311"
        ,'locationType': "C"
       
   },
   'job' : {
    
      'jobTitle' : "Service Management Business Analyst",
      'city' : "",
      'state' : "",
      'country' : "",
      'id': "3032410565",
                  'jobSource': "6938",
      'hasPostalAddress': 0,

      'hasOccupationalCategory': 1,
      'hasSalaryCurrency': 1,

                        'hasGeoCoordinates': 1,
     
     'category' : "10014",
     'expired' : 'false'
    
   },
   'test' : {
    
    'planoutIdList': [
     
      , "jobViewDomain.exp_jobViewDomain_catchall"
     
      , "savedJobsDomain.non_user_saved_jobs_catchall"
     
      , "urgency.2018_10_15_badgeDiversity"
     
      , "easyApplyDomain.exp_easyApplyDomain_catchall"
     
      , "jobDetailsDomain.exp_jobDetailsDomain_catchall"
     
      , "serpDomain.exp_serpDomain_catchall"
     
      , "serpDomain.reviseFacetCounts_2018_11_06"
     
      , "jxGlobalDomain.2018_11_20_exp_userReg"
     
      , "myJobsDomain.2018_09_06_myJobsJAFilters"
     
      , "urgency.urgency_catchall"
     
      , "jobs-view.extractedFields"
     
      , "jxGlobalDomain.exp_jxGlobalDomain_catchall"
     
      , "jx_global.2018_06_25_xToSerpUrgencyBadge"
     
      , "jobs-ux-dk-2.redirectToHome"
     
      , "jobAlertDomain.exp_jobAlertDomain_catchAll"
     
    ],
    'planoutTreatmentList': [
     
      , "jobViewDomainDefaultTreatment"
     
      , "savedJobsDefaultTreatment"
     
      , "badges_sevenByThree"
     
      , "easyApplyDefaultTreatment"
     
      , "jobDetailsDefaultTreatment"
     
      , "serpDefaultTreatment"
     
      , "reviseFacetCounts_on"
     
      , "userReg_control"
     
      , "myJobsJAFilters_on"
     
      , "urgency_default"
     
      , "false"
     
      , "jxGlobalDefaultTreatment"
     
      , "xToSerpUrgencyBadge_on"
     
      , "savedJobsRedirect-false"
     
      , "jobAlertDefaultTreatment"
     
    ]
   },
   'staticList' : {
    
   }
            
  }];

 
 window.getGdGlobals = window.getGdGlobals ||
   function() {
    return gdGlobals[0];
   };

 GD = window.GD || {};
 GD.pageInfo = GD.pageInfo || {};
 GD.pageInfo.pageGroup = getGdGlobals().page.group;
 GD.domain = getGdGlobals().page.domain;

 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your script is in a python var called `script`.

```
import json
import re
script = '''
'''
<script>
    window.gdGlobals = window.gdGlobals ||
        [{
            'analyticsId':                      "UA-2595786-1",
...
</script>
'''
script = script.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\t', ' ').replace("'", '"')
myvars = re.search(r"window.gdGlobals\s*\|\|\s*\[({.*})\];", script).group(1);
myvars = re.sub('\[\s*,', '[', myvars)
myvars = json.loads(myvars)
print(myvars['employer'])
```

yields:

```
{'size': '10000--1',
 'sector': 'Information Technology',
 'sectorId': '10013',
 'industry': 'Computer Hardware &amp; Software',
 'industryId': '200060',
 'name': 'Teradata',
 'id': '14638',
 'location': 'San Diego',
 'locationId': '1147311',
 'locationType': 'C'}
```

The regex is going to be very fragile so you are probably going to want to be more clever about it than in this example.